# Data mining: Clique based clustering to make comparison in social network analysis

Tags: python, data-mining, dataset, clustering, social-network-analysis

I am a very beginner in data mining. **I want to work on Clique based clustering method**. I want to make a comparison between various datasets for social network analysis or community detection of social network analysis. **Now I need more than 3 datasets and source code (Python code) to make the comparison in terms of social network analysis**. The data set can be older or new that would not be any problem. But **I want to work on at least 3 datasets from different domains and sizes to make a better comparison**.

Please may help me to give enough instruction.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are over 300 social networks captured in the [Index of Complex Networks](https://icon.colorado.edu/#!/).  Thats usually the best place to start.

While your quantitative method is not very clear, it sounds like you could start with [networkx](https://networkx.github.io) and use something like [find_cliques](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html).  There is also a community detection method built for all types of subgraphs, not just cliques [Benson et al. (2018)](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/353/6295/163/tab-figures-data).